# Hide/Unhide object in Unity3D via script

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

i want to set part of my scene to be hidden before everything starts, 
so lets say i have some `isHidden` (which im trying to find) property that i set to `true` before, or at the first frame of my scene.

at some point i want to unhide it and trigger the animation, i know how to trigger the animation.
and the only way i found to hid object is to set it like :

```
SetActive(false);
```

it does hide is, but when i am trying to access it later in the script with

```
GameObject.Find("gameObjectName");
```

it returns null.
so, what is the correct approach to hide or hide `GameObject` via script.
this is not a `Mesh` so it dont have a mesh renderer.

Comment: setactive doesn't affect find, check the name of the object is correct and unique

Comment: this is the name: XwingScene
he is unique. no other object called like this, and when i am trying to access it after setting SetActive(false) it returns null

Comment: ` this is not a Mesh so it dont have a mesh renderer.` do you mean it has children with the meshes in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use **Renderer.enabled**

```
bool enabled;
Description

Makes the rendered 3D object visible if enabled.
```

example code:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Show() {
        renderer.enabled = true;
    }
    void Hide() {
        renderer.enabled = false;
    }
    void HideChildren()
    {
         Renderer[] lChildRenderers=gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
         foreach ( Renderer lRenderer in lChildRenderers)
         {
              lRenderer.enabled=false;
         }
    }
    void ShowChildren()
    {
         Renderer[] lChildRenderers=gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
         foreach ( Renderer lRenderer in lChildRenderers)
         {
              lRenderer.enabled=true;
         }
    }


}
```

Comment: every GameObject have a rendrer?

Comment: Gameobject.renderer is part of every gameobject. But not every gameobject has a renderer, in which case it is null. The good news is that any scene object that is visible (as you describe) must have a renderer.