# How do I make a menu appear or disppear?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I made a menu, but I want it to be unique every time you open it, the changing of the buttons and stuff I will figure up later, the main thing is, that I need the menu to pop up, when I click a certain button / GameObject. Could anyone help please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide/Unhide object in Unity3D via script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589344/hide-unhide-object-in-unity3d-via-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
public class game : MonoBehaviour {

    public void close_btn_clicked()
    {
        your_menu_name.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

**Add this to your button to its click event. By adding this script file to an empty game object and simply drag-drop it on the button.**